# Dropping rows from the report based on commission date

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to drop rows (not show) from the report based on commission date completion.

```
SELECT  
        proj.ProjectNumber AS [Project],
        proj.UserText4 AS [Sales Rep],
        bc.Name AS [Customer Name],
        proj.Address3 AS [Shiped to], 
        proj.City,
        proj.State,
        v_InvDet.InvoiceNumber AS [Invoice],

        CASE WHEN CAST(v_InvDet.InvoiceDate  as Date) = '01/01/1900' 
        then NULL else convert(varchar(10), v_InvDet.InvoiceDate, 101) 
        END AS [Invoice Date], 

        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.UserDate4  as Date) ='01/01/1900' 
        then NULL else convert(varchar(10), proj.UserDate4, 101) 
        END AS [Install Date],

        --CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, proj.UserDate4) = '1900-01-01'
        --THEN NULL
        --ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), proj.UserDate4, 120)
        --+ ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), proj.UserDate4, 108)
        --END AS [Install Date],

        --case WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), proj.UserDate4, 120) > DATEADD( d, -30, GETDATE() )
        --THEN proj.UserDate4
        --END  AS [Install Date],

        case WHEN CONVERT(DATE, proj.UserDate4) = '1900-01-01'
        THEN NULL
        ELSE DATEDIFF(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, proj.UserDate4)*-1
        END  AS [Open Days],

        IIF(proj.UserText9  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [HVLS Fans],
        IIF(proj.UserText18  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Restrains],
        IIF(proj.UserText23  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Docks],
        IIF(proj.SitePM  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Doors],
        IIF(proj.ProjectURL  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Lifts],

        proj.UserText2 AS [Commission Equip], 

        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date)  > DATEADD( d, -14, GETDATE() ) 
        then NULL 
        else convert(varchar(10), proj.Userdate5, 101) 
        END AS [Commission Date2],

    /* Converting 01/01/1900 to NULL so it will show no date on report*/
        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date) = '01/01/1900' then NULL else convert(varchar(10), proj.Userdate5, 101) 
        END AS [Commission Date],

        --case WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date) = '01/01/1900' > DATEADD( d, -14, GETDATE() )
        --THEN proj.UserDate5
        --END  AS [Commission Date1],
        --proj.Userdate5 = DATEADD(d, 14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ),
        --proj.Userdate5 as [Commission Date],
        proj.UserText3 AS [Commission By]


FROM Project proj

LEFT JOIN v_InvoiceDetail As v_InvDet (nolock) ON proj.ProjectNumber = v_InvDet.ProjectNumber
LEFT JOIN Company AS bc (nolock) ON bc.CompanyID = proj.BillingCompanyID
WHERE
proj.Userdate5 >= DATEADD(d, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 --proj.Userdate5 >= DATEADD(d, -14, CONVERT(datetime,(convert(varchar(12),proj.Userdate5, 101)))) --getdate())-14
--proj.Userdate4 between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 

--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate >= DATEDIFF(d, proj.UserDate4, getdate())
--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD( d, -140, GETDATE() )

ORDER BY proj.UserText4
```

I am using a "where" close to filter. Is that a way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for posting code that way. It did not let me to paste my code on core section. How do I attach the code? Thanks

Comment: You can *edit* your question.

Comment: Include your code by leaving a space between your code and your sentence, pasting the code, highlighting all of it, and pressing `ctrl-k` on your keyboard.

Comment: It won't let me post a code without add a text before 'where'

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you correctly. can you elaborate what you need? do you need parameterized query?

Comment: I think I need to re- do my query for sure. The requirements are just changed again. Here is what I need to accomplish: Need to get data if 'Comm. equipment', 'Comm. Date', and 'Comm. By' are not completed in two weeks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your query with another query so that your actual query will be inner query then put your condition.

See This:

```
select * from (
    SELECT  
        proj.ProjectNumber AS [Project],
        proj.UserText4 AS [Sales Rep],
        bc.Name AS [Customer Name],
        proj.Address3 AS [Shiped to], 
        proj.City,
        proj.State,
        v_InvDet.InvoiceNumber AS [Invoice],

        CASE WHEN CAST(v_InvDet.InvoiceDate  as Date) = '01/01/1900' 
        then NULL else convert(varchar(10), v_InvDet.InvoiceDate, 101) 
        END AS [Invoice Date], 

        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.UserDate4  as Date) ='01/01/1900' 
        then NULL else convert(varchar(10), proj.UserDate4, 101) 
        END AS [Install Date],

        --CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, proj.UserDate4) = '1900-01-01'
        --THEN NULL
        --ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), proj.UserDate4, 120)
        --+ ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), proj.UserDate4, 108)
        --END AS [Install Date],

        --case WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), proj.UserDate4, 120) > DATEADD( d, -30, GETDATE() )
        --THEN proj.UserDate4
        --END  AS [Install Date],

        case WHEN CONVERT(DATE, proj.UserDate4) = '1900-01-01'
        THEN NULL
        ELSE DATEDIFF(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, proj.UserDate4)*-1
        END  AS [Open Days],

        IIF(proj.UserText9  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [HVLS Fans],
        IIF(proj.UserText18  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Restrains],
        IIF(proj.UserText23  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Docks],
        IIF(proj.SitePM  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Doors],
        IIF(proj.ProjectURL  = 'TRUE', 'YES', 'NO') AS [Lifts],

        proj.UserText2 AS [Commission Equip], 

        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date)  > DATEADD( d, -14, GETDATE() ) 
        then NULL 
        else convert(varchar(10), proj.Userdate5, 101) 
        END AS [Commission Date2],

    /* Converting 01/01/1900 to NULL so it will show no date on report*/
        CASE WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date) = '01/01/1900' then NULL else convert(varchar(10), proj.Userdate5, 101) 
        END AS [Commission Date],

        --case WHEN CAST(proj.Userdate5 as Date) = '01/01/1900' > DATEADD( d, -14, GETDATE() )
        --THEN proj.UserDate5
        --END  AS [Commission Date1],
        --proj.Userdate5 = DATEADD(d, 14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ),
        --proj.Userdate5 as [Commission Date],
        proj.UserText3 AS [Commission By]


FROM Project proj

LEFT JOIN v_InvoiceDetail As v_InvDet (nolock) ON proj.ProjectNumber = v_InvDet.ProjectNumber
LEFT JOIN Company AS bc (nolock) ON bc.CompanyID = proj.BillingCompanyID
WHERE
proj.Userdate5 >= DATEADD(d, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 --proj.Userdate5 >= DATEADD(d, -14, CONVERT(datetime,(convert(varchar(12),proj.Userdate5, 101)))) --getdate())-14
--proj.Userdate4 between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 

--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate >= DATEDIFF(d, proj.UserDate4, getdate())
--v_InvDet.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD( d, -140, GETDATE() )
)
where [Commission Date] not in ( ....) 
ORDER BY proj.UserText4
```

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the late reply. I did try to use a nested query, but it did not work ... and I dis not look too dip. Will take a pick. Thanks